# How to split the funds and send X% to fee wallet and the remaining funds to another wallet?

Tags: json-rpc, script, php

Anybody have any idea about how to do it?

1. User send the bitcoins
2. X% goes to fee wallet
3. remaining funds goes to service wallet

[image: Scheme]

I'm trying to use the "sendfrom" but it's not working because he only send the fee amount (or the first call), never the rest.

```
$sendingFee = $bitcoin->sendfrom($account, $addFee, $feeFormated, 0);
$sendingRest = $bitcoin->sendfrom($account, $addRest, $restMath, 0);
```

This is my code:

```
<?php

require("easybitcoin.php");
$bitcoin = new Bitcoin("root", "000000", "localhost", "18332");

function fee($fee, $bal){
    $final = ($fee / 100) * $bal;
    return $final;
}

#account
$account = "pizza";

#fee address
$addFee = "2N9xQyV6itnZNBv5NSLUy8ffXcfopVvP19v";

#Rest address
$addRest = "2MtEzMsT9eedTms9ivEQnjuHPRWw1DHnxyT";

#% charged
$tax = 10;

#balance
$balance = $bitcoin->getbalance($account, 1);

#do a math to remove X%
$feeMath = fee($tax, $balance);

#I was receiving "invalid amount" error. Fixed with this, I was giving 9 instead of 8 after zero. See satoshis for more.
$feeFormated = number_format($feeMath, 8);

#remove the fee from current balance
$restMath = $balance - $feeFormated;

#send the fee to the address xxxx
$sendingFee = $bitcoin->sendfrom($account, $addFee, $feeFormated, 0);

#send the balance minus fee to the address yyy
$sendingRest = $bitcoin->sendfrom($account, $addRest, $restMath, 0);

$err = $bitcoin->error;

#Print message for control
print_r("Fee <b>TXID</b> = " . $sendingFee . " Amount sent = " . "<b>" . $feeFormated . "</b><br><br>");
print_r("Rest <b>TXID</b> = " . $sendingRest . " Amount sent = " . "<b>" . $restMath . "</b><br><br>");

print_r("It's not working because: " . $err);

echo var_dump($sendingFee) . "<br><br>";
echo var_dump($sendingRest) . "<br><br>";


?>
```

It's not perfect (far from this) but please understand, I'm not a php guy, even a programmer, I'm just working in a personal project as a hobby.

Maybe should I use "sendmany"? If so, how to use this with php? I saw some examples on internet but nothing showing how to use with php and variables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved using "sendmany":

```
<?php
#SENDMANY WORKING
require("easybitcoin.php");
$bitcoin = new Bitcoin("root", "000000", "localhost", "18332");

$account = "pizza";

$arrayRec = array("2MsWztzmaxnsU3xetrKsD4E9ep4r2gYtXj9" => "0.00111", 
                "2Mt7dkQiyExrNQTXu9D3qoCpWg3J5TJy9Up" => "0.00222" );

$send = $bitcoin->sendmany($account, $arrayRec);

print_r($send);

?>
```